# Crash when array is nil

Tags: objective-c, arrays, gdb

Trying to avoid a crash when an NSMutableArray, myArray, is nil.

Here's my line of code to check if the array is nil:

```
if (!self.myArray || !self.myArray.count){
```

I've set a break point just before this line and, to make it nil, I go into gdb and do:

```
(gdb) set self.myArray = nil
(gdb) po self.myArray
0x11064e8 does not appear to point to a valid object.
```

When I step over the **if** I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. What gives?

Comment: It appears to be the case that self.myArray is actually *not nil*, instead it's a non-NULL, invalid pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This checks if your array is nil and has an element.

```
if (myArray != nil && [self.myArray count] > 0){
```

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Cheks whether your array is nil or it doesn't have any item

```
if (!myArray || myArray.count==0) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely both tests are done, or the second test is done first, in which case it tries to access count from the nil object and raises an error.